# Find string length in sql without starting of zero

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv

I have a problem, I am uploading employee code and Account Number from excel(.csv) file, and I will check the employee code and update or insert the Account Number for the corresponding Employee Code. But If the employee code is start with "0" csv file will not consider the 0's and just send the remaining character, so when I check it in sql will not match with table data (Employee Code).

I have a plan to match them, but I don't know how to do.

I have Tried Below Query

```
declare @EmployeeCodeNET varchar(max)='MJ300'; 
declare @EmployeeCodeDB varchar(max)='00MJ300';


select LTRIM(REPLACE(@EmployeeCodeDB, '0', ''))--It should return 'MJ300'
```

Comment: mysql <> sql server. which one do you use?

Comment: LTRIM() remove the zero on both side (starting and ending) but I need to remove the 0's only starting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If spaces are not expected, then something *close* to what you tried is what you need:

```
declare @EmployeeCodeDB varchar(max)='00MJ300';

select REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(@EmployeeCodeDB, '0', ' ')),' ','0')
```

That is, replace all `0`s with spaces, then (`LTRIM`) remove all *leading* spaces, and then replace all spaces with `0`s (so, all original `0`s which weren't in a leading position are reverted back)

Result:

```
MJ300
```

---

If spaces may exist in your string and they're not required, but they shouldn't magically turn into `0`s, then you can replace the inner `@EmployeeCodeDB` with yet another replace: `REPLACE(@EmployeeCodeDB,' ','')`

Answer (score 3):

Solution with `PATINDEX`:

```
declare @str varchar(max)=' 00MJ300';
SELECT SUBSTRING(@str, PATINDEX('%[^0 ]%', @str), LEN(@str))
```

It will find the first symbol that is not 0 or space and take substring starting at that position till the end.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @EmployeeCodeNET varchar(max)='MJ300'; 
declare @EmployeeCodeDB varchar(max)='00MJ300';
DECLARE @offset int

SELECT @offset = LEN(@EmployeeCodeDB) - LEN(@EmployeeCodeNET)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@EmployeeCodeDB, @offset+1, LEN(@EmployeeCodeNET))
```

Comment: thanks but the above one(written by Damien) is very speed

Comment: I know, i was only making something more general